# Convert pandas df to orc bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, orc

Following is generated by this line of code:

```
table_bytes = df.to_parquet()
```

```
table_bytes: b'PAR1\x15\x04\x15@\x15DL\x15\x08\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00 |\x03\x00\x00\x00Tom\x04\x00\x00\x00nick\x05\x00\x00\x00krish\x04\x00\x00\x00jack\x15\x00\x15\x14\x15\x18,\x15\x08\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c6\x00(\x04nick\x18\x03Tom\x00\x00\x00\n$\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x02\x03\xe4\x00&\xc0\x01\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\rcustomer_name\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xb0\x01\x16\xb8\x01&h&\x08\x1c6\x00(\x04nick\x18\x03Tom\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x04\x15@\x15@L\x15\x08\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00 \x0c\x84\x90\x01\x00\x01\x01\x08\xc2\x15\x02\x01\x07@\x00\x97\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x15\x14\x15\x18,\x15\x08\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c\x18\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n$\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x02\x03\xe4\x00&\xc2\x04\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x0bcustomer_id\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xea\x01\x16\xee\x01&\xb0\x03&\xd4\x02\x1c\x18\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x04\x15@\x15<L\x15\x08\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00 \x08\xe8\x03\x00\x05\x01\x04\xc0\x12\x05\x07@\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x15\x14\x15\x18,\x15\x08\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c\x18\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n$\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x02\x03\xe4\x00&\xfa\x07\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x14purchase_amt_last_30\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xea\x01\x16\xea\x01&\xe8\x06&\x90\x06\x1c\x18\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x04\x156\x15:L\x15\x02\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00\x1bh\x17\x00\x00\x002022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x15\x00\x15\x12\x15\x16,\x15\x08\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c6\x00(\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x18\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x00\x00\x00\t \x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x01\x08\x00&\xd4\x0b\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\ractivity_time\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xf2\x01\x16\xfa\x01&\xb0\n&\xda\t\x1c6\x00(\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x18\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x04\x15\n\x15\x0eL\x15\x02\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00\x05\x10\x01\x00\x00\x006\x15\x00\x15\x12\x15\x16,\x15\x08\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c6\x00(\x016\x18\x016\x00\x00\x00\t \x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x01\x08\x00&\xb0\x0e\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x05month\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16n\x16v&\xe4\r&\xba\r\x1c6\x00(\x016\x18\x016\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x02\x19l5\x00\x18\x06schema\x15\n\x00\x15\x0c%\x02\x18\rcustomer_name%\x00L\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x15\x04%\x02\x18\x0bcustomer_id\x00\x15\x04%\x02\x18\x14purchase_amt_last_30\x00\x15\x0c%\x02\x18\ractivity_time%\x00L\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x15\x0c%\x02\x18\x05month%\x00L\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x16\x08\x19\x1c\x19\\&\xc0\x01\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\rcustomer_name\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xb0\x01\x16\xb8\x01&h&\x08\x1c6\x00(\x04nick\x18\x03Tom\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00&\xc2\x04\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x0bcustomer_id\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xea\x01\x16\xee\x01&\xb0\x03&\xd4\x02\x1c\x18\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x13\xd9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x84\x90\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00&\xfa\x07\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x14purchase_amt_last_30\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xea\x01\x16\xea\x01&\xe8\x06&\x90\x06\x1c\x18\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08u"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00&\xd4\x0b\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\ractivity_time\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16\xf2\x01\x16\xfa\x01&\xb0\n&\xda\t\x1c6\x00(\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x18\x172022-06-11 19:23:16.477\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00&\xb0\x0e\x1c\x15\x0c\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x05month\x15\x02\x16\x08\x16n\x16v&\xe4\r&\xba\r\x1c6\x00(\x016\x18\x016\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x16\xe4\x07\x16\x08&\x08\x16\x80\x08\x14\x00\x00\x19,\x18\x06pandas\x18\xac\x07{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "stop": 4, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "customer_name", "field_name": "customer_name", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "customer_id", "field_name": "customer_id", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "purchase_amt_last_30", "field_name": "purchase_amt_last_30", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "activity_time", "field_name": "activity_time", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "month", "field_name": "month", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"library": "pyarrow", "version": "7.0.0"}, "pandas_version": "1.3.3"}\x00\x18\x0cARROW:schema\x18\x8c\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\x00\x18\x1fparquet-cpp-arrow version 7.0.0\x19\\\x1c\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00PAR1'
```

I wish to generate the similar thing for a orc file. I am able to generate a ORC file by following code:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
table_bytes = orc.write_table(table, orc_file)
```

However, it writes an orc file. I want something that to_parquet provides (which is in the form of bytes.

Any idea on how can I achieve that?

Thank you so much in advance. Hope what I mentioned makes sense. Otherwise, please let me know and I will provide further context.

Comment: df.to_orc is expected soon, it might work then. <https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44554#:~:text=%5BEHN%5D-,pandas.DataFrame.to_orc,-%2344554>

Answer (score 1):

I got it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import orc


df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3]})
print(df.to_parquet())

# Wrote the table to a file and then read bytes from it.

orc.write_table(pa.table({"col1": [1, 2, 3]}), "test.orc")
with open('test.orc', "rb") as file:
    bytes_read = file.read()
print(bytes_read)
```

```
b'PAR1\x15\x04\x150\x15.L\x15\x06\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00\x18\x04\x01\x00\t\x01<\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x15\x14\x15\x18,\x15\x06\x15\x04\x15\x06\x15\x06\x1c\x18\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n$\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x02\x03$\x00&\xe4\x01\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x04col1\x15\x02\x16\x06\x16\xda\x01\x16\xdc\x01&R&\x08\x1c\x18\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x15\x02\x19,5\x00\x18\x06schema\x15\x02\x00\x15\x04%\x02\x18\x04col1\x00\x16\x06\x19\x1c\x19\x1c&\xe4\x01\x1c\x15\x04\x195\x04\x00\x06\x19\x18\x04col1\x15\x02\x16\x06\x16\xda\x01\x16\xdc\x01&R&\x08\x1c\x18\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00(\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19,\x15\x04\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x15\x00\x15\x04\x15\x02\x00\x00\x00\x16\xda\x01\x16\x06&\x08\x16\xdc\x01\x14\x00\x00\x19,\x18\x06pandas\x18\xab\x03{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "stop": 3, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "col1", "field_name": "col1", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"library": "pyarrow", "version": "7.0.0"}, "pandas_version": "1.3.5"}\x00\x18\x0cARROW:schema\x18\xb8\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\x00\x18\x1fparquet-cpp-arrow version 7.0.0\x19\x1c\x1c\x00\x00\x00\xb7\x05\x00\x00PAR1'

b'ORC\n\x0b\n\x03\x00\x00\x00\x12\x04\x08\x03P\x00\n\x15\n\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x0c\x08\x03\x12\x06\x08\x02\x10\x06\x18\x0cP\x00\xff\xe0\xff\xe0F\x02$`\n\x06\x08\x06\x10\x00\x18\r\n\x06\x08\x06\x10\x01\x18\x17\n\x06\x08\x00\x10\x00\x18\x02\n\x06\x08\x00\x10\x01\x18\x02\n\x06\x08\x01\x10\x01\x18\x04\x12\x04\x08\x00\x10\x00\x12\x04\x08\x02\x10\x00\x1a\x03GMT\n\x14\n\x04\x08\x03P\x00\n\x0c\x08\x03\x12\x06\x08\x02\x10\x06\x18\x0cP\x00\x08\x03\x10e\x1a\n\x08\x03\x10$\x18\x08 9(\x03"\x11\x08\x0c\x12\x01\x01\x1a\x04col1 \x00(\x000\x00"\x08\x08\x04 \x00(\x000\x000\x03:\x04\x08\x03P\x00:\x0c\x08\x03\x12\x06\x08\x02\x10\x06\x18\x0cP\x00@\x90NH\x01b\x051.7.2\x08O\x10\x00\x18\x80\x80\x04"\x02\x00\x0c(\x160\x06\x82\xf4\x03\x03ORC\x17'
```

On Windows 10 it gives an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._orc'. In google colab worked without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with pandas v.1.5.0, there is a to_orc function that returns bytes. Simply pass `None` to the path argument.

```
DataFrame.to_orc(path=None, *, engine='pyarrow', index=None, engine_kwargs=None)

Returns
bytes if no path argument is provided else None
```

See documentation below:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_orc.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_orc